# How can I set a scope variable, test a controller, then change the scope variable and re-load the controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have something like this in my controller code.

```
$scope.parsedDisabled = $scope.isDisabled === 'true' ? true : false;
```

This isn't run inside any sort of function, it's the first line of code run when the controller gets created.

So when I'm doing my unit tests I have something like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $filter) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        filter = $filter;
        scope.isDisabled = 'true';
        controller = $controller('toggleRadioController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    describe('test stuff', function(){
        it('Should set to true', function(){
            expect(scope.parsedDisabled).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```

So this is all well and good, but then I want to be able to run that same test, but with scope.isDisabled set to `'false'`, and then again with it set to `undefined`. My issue here is that this obviously needs to be changed to false and undefined *before* the controller is actually loaded, and I don't know how to do that in this case. I've tried screwing around with nested `beforeEach()`'s but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define an array that contains **isDisabled** values in the same order of your tests.
Then make a counter that increments **afterEach** test. Finally, set **scope.isDisabled** to *array[counter]*.

Here is it:

```
describe('test stuff', function(){
    var disabledValues = ['true', 'false', undefined],
        counter = 0;

    beforeEach(module('plunker'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $filter) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        filter = $filter;
        scope.isDisabled = disabledValues[counter];
        controller = $controller('toggleRadioController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));
    afterEach(function() {
        counter += 1;
    });


    it('"true" should set to true', function(){
        expect(scope.parsedDisabled).toBe(true);
    });

    it('"false" should set to false', function(){
        expect(scope.parsedDisabled).toBe(false);
    });

    it('"undefined" should set to false', function(){
        expect(scope.parsedDisabled).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

And here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMEjrEzGPDGM8RbBmyRe?p=preview) for it.